# std::vector emplace_back doesn't return reference to inserted element in MSVC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I'm getting a compiler error https://godbolt.org/z/jEEs9Kcx6 when using emplace_back function to assign the returned reference to a reference variable in MSVC but not in GCC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vecs;

    auto& str1 = vecs.emplace_back("Hello, world!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux updated my post by providing link.

Comment: Your project is not compiling for C++17. On godbolt it compiles fine with `/std:c++17` https://godbolt.org/z/zWfsnrTMh

Comment: GCC 12 uses C++17 by-default. MSVC does not. Add the correct flags and it will work: https://godbolt.org/z/o1M16vvYe (`emplace_back` only returns a reference since C++17)